# code help for stored procedure dll class

Tags: c#

i m making dll class for stored procedure as...help me to correct it...my boss said that i m missing parameter values to return but i m not getting anything to correct it...

```
public class transactionService

{

SqlConnection cs;


private void OpenConnection()

{

cs = new SqlConnection();

cs.ConnectionString = "Data Source=IRIS-CSG-174;Initial Catalog=library_system;Integrated Security=True";

cs.Open();

}

public membership_details calculatefine()

{

OpenConnection();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.CommandText = "Exec member_fine_detail";

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("member_id", SqlDbType.Int));



membership_details myObjec = new membership_details();

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

myObjec.fine_per_day = 0;


return myObjec;
```

help me to correct this code...i m trying to get fne_per_day as per member_id and after this reference is adding to return form in project from that according to member_id fine_per_day is calculated...as the creteria is like member_id=5,membership_desc=silver,gol,platinum,fineperday=30or 20or10

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need something like this for returning the out parameter of your stored procedure:

```
public membership_details calculatefine()
{

     OpenConnection();

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

     cmd.CommandText = "Exec member_fine_detail";

     cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@member_id", SqlDbType.Int));

     //Sql parameter corresponding to the output parameter
     cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fine_per_day", SqlDbType.Int));
     cmd.Parameters[cmd.Parameters.Count - 1].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

     //execute the stored procedure
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

     //obtain the value for the output parameter
     myObjec.fine_per_day = (int)cmd.Parameters["@fine_per_day"].Value;

     return myObjec;
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply...but i want fine_per day as calculated with acc to member_is so will this code work well??? and what about calculatefine() class my boss said i also hv to do smthing of it...soo plzzz help me!!!